# Flex: The CSS type selector was not processed because the type was not used in the application

Tags: apache-flex

When I use a custom skin for my app I get these warnings all over the place. Yes I know why. But I don't need to be told this, and I don't like all the yellow icons cluttering up my workspace. I know if I remove the unused classes they will go away but 1) if later I decide to add a component I want the class to be in-place to style it and 2) my skin is in a shared location so even if this app doesn't use a particular class another app using the same skin probably does. So does anyone know a way to tell flex builder to ignore this particular type of warning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the "Additional compiler arguments" box of the Flex Compiler section of your Project Properties, append the following to disable warnings about unused CSS type selectors:

```
-show-unused-type-selector-warnings=false
```

It works just fine.

Don't just disable all warnings, it's really important to know that bindings might fail etc.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but check it out...

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=12748

or this:

http://www.derekentringer.com/blog/flex-builder-remove-css-type-selector-warnings/